# React Native: How to keep keyboard open when input loses in Webview?

Tags: html, react-native, webview, focus

I have two input elements and I need to change focus from one input to another.

But when the input loses focus, the keyboard will dismiss too.

Is there any way to keep keyboard open?

```
export default function Test() {
    const viewHTML = `
        <html>
            <body>
                <script>
                    function test1() {
                        // document.getElementById("test2").focus()
                        document.getElementById("test1").blur()
                    }
                </script>
                <input id="test1" oninput="test1()" style="height:60px"/>
                <input id="test2"  style="height:60px"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    `;
    return (
            <View>
                <WebView
                    style={{width:370, height:600}}
                    hideKeyboardAccessoryView={true}
                    keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction={false}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                    source={{ html: viewHTML}}
                />
            </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the behaviour you want is:

- user enters some text in `test1` input,
- user taps enter
- `test2` input gains focus
- keyboard is visible at all times

then you should use the `onchange` event and trigger `focus` instead of `blur`:

```html
<script>
  function test1() {
    document.getElementById("test2").focus()
  }
</script>
<input id="test1" onchange="test1()" style="height:60px"/>
```

You can find a snack of this solution here: https://snack.expo.dev/@mlisik/jealous-waffles (needs to be run on a device).